# Object Permission returns false even with Admin Profile

Tags: apex, privileges, access, admin

Currently, I have a class that essentially builds a JSON so I can read it in a pretty HTML5 interface. This class has some conditions to build the JSON. Some object fields, for instance, are not visible for some profiles, so I can't put the object information in the JSON if the user who executed the class doesn't have the privileges to read it.

I have the following code:

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult myFeatureAccess= MyCustomObject.MyFeatureField__c.sObjectType.getDescribe();

if(myFeatureAccess.isAccessible())
{
    System.debug('User has access to the feature [MyFeature].');
    result += '"fat":"' + MyCustomObject[i].MyFeatureField__c+ '",';
}
```

It does not work. When I access it with my non-admin profile (with visibility unchecked for that field), the class still generates the JSON with that field.

Does anyone know why? Might be something related to the fact that the class that generates the JSON is static?

Comment: I find the first line of your code confusing; I would expect you to be aiming to get a [DescribeFieldResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_fields_describe) not a [DescribeSObjectResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_sobject_describe).

Comment: I also removed the .sObjectType from the method, and this worked. Thank you! Can you please answer my question so I can mark your answer as the solution? :)

Comment: I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get information for the field the [describe call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_fields_describe) you need is:

```
DescribeFieldResult myFeatureAccess = MyCustomObject.MyFeatureField__c.getDescribe();
```